# Mod Rewrite Removing Query(GET) Details

Tags: php, .htaccess

For some reason my Rewrite in my htaccess is causing some issues with my $_GET variables.

when I go to /?action=test I can get action from $_GET, as soon as I go to /api/?action=test I lose my $_GET variables.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried adding the Query String Attached [QSA] with no avail. I've tried both [QSA,L] and [L,QSA]

Objective: Friendly URLs with automatic trailing slash. My php takes the URL as an array: /some/url/location provides urlArray("some","url","location)

I have fairly well removed my array out of the possibilities of what might be causing the issue. I placed all my test code before this function happens to ensure this wasn't my problem.

Comment: If that is all you have in your `.htaccess` file then the "problem" is not with your `.htaccess` file (that will retain the query string under all circumstances). When you say you "lose my $_GET variables" - is the query string removed from the visible URL in the browser's address bar? The problem is with your PHP code. If you create a simple PHP script, with the above `.htaccess` code you will see that the query string is present and the `action` URL parameter is readable.

Comment: Incidentally, the `QSA` flag is only required if you are including a query string in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ and you wish to all append the query string from the request - so they are _merged_. If you are not including a query string in `.htaccess` (as in your example) then the query string is appended by default.

Comment: @MrWhite the parameters are still in the url at all times .  The same code is used on / and on /api/ which really confused me on why the / page shows the get parameters in code, but no subsequent pages do. Truly confusing, especially since I've used this code on several other websites without problem. I'll keep searching, thanks for confirming it's not htaccess.

Comment: @MrWhite , I have taken var_dump($_GET) and placed it as the very first code in my index.php file, and added exit() just after it so NO other code runs. I get "array(0) { }" on /api/?action=test. The same code ran on /?action=test results in "array(1) { ["action"]=> string(4) "test" }".

Comment: Does `/api` exist as a physical directory?

Comment: @MrWhite , It does but, My index file  sorts and includes files based on the array built from the url. As mentioned in my question "My php takes the URL as an array: /some/url/location provides urlArray("some","url","location)" then using that info I build my pages. From my index page: elseif ($urlPathArray[0] == "api"){
    require_once 'api/api.php';
}

Comment: Strangly, if I go to the file directly /api/api.php the parameters are available.

Comment: @MrWhite , So i think your mention of the folder was the issue. However I am not aware of WHY. I moved /api/ folder under my views folder and updated my index file to point to this new location. /api/?action=test now provides a value. I must be missing some knowledge LOL